# How can I add an onmouseover event to all drupal forms?

Tags: forms, drupal, button, themes, onmouseover

I want to add an onmouseover event to the submit button of all forms on my drupal site.

How can I do this?

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="submit"]').hover(
      function(){ 
        // Do something with $(this)
      }
    );
});
```

**EDIT:** Updated with another possible solution since you just need to update the background color.

If you don't care about IE6 support, you can also use the [`:hover`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pseudo_hover.asp) CSS pseudo selector for your submit buttons and don't need any javascript.  Make sure all your submit buttons have a class set to them (I'm using `'submit'` as the class name in this example).

```
.submit {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.submit:hover {
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the above can be done either in the theme or in a custom module. If using the custom module route (which may or may not make sense depending on what's being accomplished), just use hook_init to add some JS using drupal_add_js() and you're on your way.

Comment: Also instead of using $(document).ready it's a good idea to do it the Drupal way and add a behaviour, see here for details: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--javascript_startup_guide.html/6#Drupal.behaviors

Comment: I had a look at the link. I'm not sure where I would put the code. I basically am trying to change all my buttons so that onmouseover they all turn red. Can you give me a little bit more explanation please?

Thanks.

Comment: See my updated answer for another possible solution using the :hover CSS pseudo selector.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to take into account ie6 which was why I want to follow a javascript solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to partly resolve my problem by adding the following code to a custom module:

```
function defprofile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['submit']['#attributes'] = array('onMouseOver' => "this.style.backgroundColor='#cc0000'",'onMouseOut' => "this.style.backgroundColor='#000'"); }
```

However, this only works for submit buttons, and I want it to work for all buttons. I've tried replacing 'submit' with 'button' but then the code stops working altogether.